# c# httpclient in pcl caching issue

Tags: c#, caching, httpclient

I am using HttpClient in a Portable Class Library to make http requests to an api

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();//also adding authorization and user agent headers 
 HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri));
 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //and then handle the response after that
```

the above code works fine in receiving responses.
My issue is that my client does not cache the responses according to the headers in the response

Cache-Control: private, max-age=300

I cannot use the WebRequestHandler to set it to the default caching policy to get the caching info from the response headers (I think because it is a pcl)

Why is this not caching properly? can I get this to do it manually after receiving the request?

Comment: Are you re-using the same httpClient instance between calls?   When you use SendAsync with a new HttpRequestMessage I think that removes all cache authorzations.  It is like a custom header override. Try to use the methods besides SendAsync and try to use the DefaultRequestHeaders and not a NEW HttpRequestMessage

Comment: Yes, it is the same instance. I tried it with await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri); , still no caching

Comment: also, the cache-control header in response is something I checked with fiddler. However,I checked the response.Headers in response, and CacheControl is null. Isn't this supposed to get values like max age automatically?